# SP10: Document Library that has "Assigned To" column added duplicate in a task list?

Tags: tasks

I have created a document library for other departments to submit documents. I created a column "Assign to" that can have a person added. Is there a way for this to duplicate on a task list that would be used for internal use? I do not want to upload the same document twice in two different places.

Comment: Upload twice = bad idea. Duplicate = bad idea too for the same reasons.